# Active directory authetication in IE

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I would like to be automatically logged on a website using my password an login that are used on my computer when i open an AD session.

Connection must be granted if i'm in the right AD group .

Any advices ?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to use the built-in ASP.NET Membership and Role system and just use the "Active Directory" membership and role providers.

That way, your user is automatically authenticated, and you can use role-based security in ASP.NET to do something like:

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction=Demand, Role='MyAppRole')]
```

Put this on your critical or sensitvie methods to allow or refuse access to your app.

With the same method, you can also add protected subfolders to your application and protect them by specifying who has access (or not) in your web.config (in that folder).

See a few links for additional details:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/gduthie/archive/2005/08/17/452905.aspx
- http://slalomdev.blogspot.com/2008/08/active-directory-role-provider.html
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.activedirectorymembershipprovider.aspx

Hope this helps a bit.

Marc